When a quotient of $\mathbb Z_p[[x,y]]$ is a regular local ring
Consider the power series in two variables with p-adic coefficients. Namely consider $\mathbb Z_p[[x,y]]$. Moreover let $c\in\mathbb Z_p$  and construct the quotient:
$$
W=\mathbb Z_p[[x,y]]/(xy-c)
$$
Now I would like to prove the following thing:

$W$ is a regular local ring if and only if $v_p(c)\le 1$

Do you have any suggestions?

If $v_p(c) > 1$ then the ideal $\mathfrak m = (p,x,y)$ cannot be generated by $2 = \dim(W)$ elements. So, $W$ is not regular.
If $v_p(c) = 1$ then $c = pu$ with $u$ a unit. Replacing $x$ by $u^{-1}x$ you can assume $c = p$. In that case, $\{x,y\}$ is a regular sequence in $W$ --- since $W/xW \simeq \mathbb F_p[[y]]$ is a domain. So, $W$ is regular (of dimension 2).
If $v_p(c) = 0$ then as in the previous paragraph we can assume that $c = 1$. So $W = \mathbb{Z}_p[[x,y]]/(xy-1)$. Then $\{p,x\}$ is a regular sequence --- since $W/pW \simeq \mathbb F_p[[x,y]]/(xy-1)$ is a 1-dimensional domain.
